# Delete RegistryKey Win64/32

Tags: delphi, registry

I am trying to delete a Windows key using Delphi , however unsuccessfully , follows the code I'm using

```
Function DeleteKeyAPI(hRoot: HKEY; sPath: String; IsReg64: BOOL): BOOL;
Var
  iRet: Integer;
Begin
  If IsReg64 Then
    iRet := RegDeleteKeyEx(hRoot, PChar(sPath), KEY_WOW64_64KEY, 0)
  Else
    iRet := RegDeleteKeyEx(hRoot, PChar(sPath), KEY_WOW64_32KEY, 0);

  If iRet = ERROR_SUCCESS Then
    Result := True
  Else
    Result := False;
End;
```

in some keys I can delete more than one has in own Regedit me of an access denied error

how can I fix this problem ?

Edited -----------------------

I tried to do as follows , but without success

```
function SHDeleteKey(key: HKEY; pszSubKey: LPCTSTR): DWORD; stdcall;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function SHDeleteKey; external 'shlwapi.dll' name 'SHDeleteKeyA';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SHDeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\AdobeCS6ServiceManager');
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should inspect the value of `iRet` to learn more. This is a Win32 error code that will give more details of the reason for failure.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724847.aspx):

> The subkey to be deleted must not have subkeys. To delete a key and all its subkeys, you need to enumerate the subkeys and delete them individually. To delete keys recursively, use the RegDeleteTree or SHDeleteKey function.

This is one common failure mode, namely that the subkey you are attempting to delete has subkeys itself. I'm not sure what error code is, perhaps `ERROR_DIR_NOT_EMPTY`.

Another common failure mode is that the named subkey does not exist. That would lead to error code `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` or perhaps `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Finally, and what I guess is the real problem, you cannot obtain delete rights to the key. Since you are using alternate registry flags, I suspect you are trying to delete a subkey under HKLM. Your process needs sufficient rights to be able to do this. Typically that means running as an elevated admin user. You will get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` if you have insufficient rights.

---

Regarding your edit, `AdobeCS6ServiceManager` is a value rather than a key. The function you need is `RegDeleteValue`. Read about the registry to learn what these terms mean: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724182.aspx

Furthermore, it is disappointing that you ask a question about `RegDeleteKeyEx` and then edit to show code that calls `SHDeleteKey`. Please try to stick to the original question.

Comment: even running it as administrator it does not erase the key, regedit own (also run as administrator ) returns me the following error:
"Unable to delete all specified values"

Comment: If you cannot find the value of `iRet`, then it's difficult to know what to say. Are you sure it is impossible for you to obtain that value?

Comment: That's a value and not a key. Please don't change the question again.

Comment: No. My answer is accurate. You need to step back and stop hacking at this at random. Think! Learn the difference between a key and a value. You are trying to delete a value. Do some research. Don't flail wildly.